# Random Hard freezes with newly-assembled PC

Tags: windows-8, cpu, freeze

[Here's my build](http://pcpartpicker.com/user/AlexMax/saved/1yGJ)

I just assembled a new computer and by now it's probably a month or two old. It's mostly pretty great. However, at least once a week, maybe once every two weeks, it'll hard freeze. Sometimes it does this while I'm using it, sometimes it does this while I'm sleeping or at work.

When I'm at the computer when it hard freezes, there is no bluescreen or anything, things just....stop. I hear the hard drive thrash for a minute, but eventually it stops too. Both times it happened I was doing nothing more strenuous than a few tabs in Firefox open. The reset button on the front of my PC doesn't do anything, and neither does the power button unless I hold it.

I've already ran MemTest86+ overnight, and no issues were reported.  Crystal Disk Info gave my hard drive a clean bill of health.  There's nothing in my event logs either.  My PC stays within acceptable temperatures all the time...I don't think I've ever noticed my CPU temp above 50 degrees C, even while playing a CPU-taxing game like Planetside 2.  The only thing that I find worrisome is my CPU voltages, they are as follows:

```
+12V: 12.29V solid
+5V: Varies between 5.12V and 5.16V.
Core: Varies between 0.78V and 1.09V, I think I've seen it in the 1.10V's as well.
Aux: 2.11V solid.
+3.3V: Varies between 3.39V and 3.41V.
```

Is that much CPU voltage variance normal?

Comment: Seems like a weak PSU considering your graphics card. Are you able to test the PC with a better one?

Comment: 3.3 v should be okay *up to* 3.5 (by normal CMOS logic levels) however the range you show doesnt seem to have a variance *down to* 3.30 or below i.e. it doesnt go below 3.39, so it may be considered a tiny tiny bit high, depending on the down stream tolerances. Other than that though I would not suspect the PSU as it would be more obv under load and you spec that it happens randomly with regard to load.

Comment: If you've over clocked without checking stability of the CPU, then that could be your problem. Run SuperPi under the standard OCing settings to see if your clock is stable. I would have also run memtest for a lot longer than overnight, 24hours minimum.

Comment: I actually haven't touched the OC, it's running at stock speeds.  I was planning on it, but I got my first freeze a few days after assembly and I didn't want to risk overclocking before I found out what was wrong in the first place.